# Hiding instance variables in the EyeInspector or EyeExplorer

Tags: reflection, smalltalk, pharo, inspector

Sometimes I am inspecting or exploring my dowmain objects which contains many instance variables. I want to exclude all of them excepting the current specific ones of the instance I am exploring.

Say I am inspecting MyObject with instance variables: text, size, status.

- dependents
- owner
- window
- announcer
- ...(lots of i.v.)
- text
- size
- status

I want to view:

- text
- size
- status

I have seen you can define the method inspectorClass, but is EyeInspector or EyeExplorer designed to configure this type of view? 
Should I subclass SelfEyeElement class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried and came up with this:

Imagine this is your class:

```
Object subclass: #MyClass
    instanceVariableNames: 'firstVariable secondVariable thirdVariable'
    classVariableNames: ''
    category: 'MyCategory'
```

Then make the following inspector class:

```
EyeInspector subclass: #MyClassInspector
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    category: 'MyCategory'
```

Add the following *class* method to `MyClass`:

```
inspectorClass
    ^ MyClassInspector
```

And overwrite `#addInstanceVariable:` in `MyClassInspector`:

```
addInstancesVariable: elements
    elements add: (InstanceVariableEyeElement host: self object instVarName: #firstVariable).
    elements add: (InstanceVariableEyeElement host: self object instVarName: #secondVariable)
```

Inspect an instance of `MyClass` and it shows only `firstVariable` and `secondVariable` but not `thirdVariable`:

[image: MyClassInspector]

Very nice question!

Update: If you want an inspector that shows generally only instance variables specified in the class of an inspected object and not in superclasses of an inspected object you can use this `#addInstanceVariable:` in your inspector class:

```
addInstancesVariable: elements
    self object class instVarNames do: [:name |
        elements add: (InstanceVariableEyeElement host: self object instVarName: name) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to work with the customizable [tools](http://www.humane-assessment.com/blog/installing-gtoolkit/) in Moose. There you can add/change views very easily. In the [humane assessment blog](http://www.humane-assessment.com/blog/dynamic-exploration-of-a-postgres-db-with-the-gtinspector/) you can find examples